# Chaining a scope to pagination method

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm trying to chain a scope to the pagination method but I'm instead getting a badmethodcallexception for the method instead;

```
$products = Product::paginate(3)->forstore();
```

The forstore method is the scope.

```
public function scopeForstore($query) {
  ...
}
```

How can I achieve the desired result i.e. add a scope to pagination query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->paginate(x)`, `->get()`, `->first()`... methods end the query. They tell the query it's time to return the result (and they return either collection or model). What you're doing is calling scope on a collection rather than query.

Swap them around:

```
$products = Product::forstore()->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should apply your scope before calling the paginate function, directly on the builder, like so:

```
Product::forstore()->paginate(3);
```